# Simulating data movement while executing assembly instructions using Generic CPU diagram

Tags: assembly, cpu, cpu-architecture

[image: Image of cpu diagram]

I don't if here is the right category for my question. I was giving an assignment to simulate the data movement of this three assembly instruction on an ARM cpu diagram above.

```
1. mov  r3,r1

2. ldr  r5,[lr]

3. stmfd   sp!,{r4,r5,r6,lr}
```

of course I know what this instruction do but I have not been able to find any resource that explain in details about the in built flow in a CPU make this instruction work.
So I am looking out for any reference or any explanation about how the CPU make this instruction happen using the cpu diagram above.

Comment: The instruction were seperately given. I know what the instruction do but don't know how the cpu works to execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"this instruction" - which one? You showed three. Also, if you know what each does, why can't you follow it on the diagram?

Anyway, let's take the first one, the `mov r3,r1`. It's logical to start from the box called "program counter". Going through the multiplexer that places the current instruction fetch address onto the address bus. The memory subsystem then replies with the instruction word on the data bus. That goes through the "instruction reg" into the "instruction decoder" which then drives the control signals for the execution of the instruction. First it tells the "register file" to place the source register `r1` into the output multiplexer from which it goes into the ALU that is programmed for a no operation because this is just a simple copy instruction (`mov`). The unchanged value goes through the "output register" to the data bus. The instruction decoder then tells the top right multiplexer to take that and forward it to the register file storing it into the destination register `r3`.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I think I understand. How about the ldr instruction. Or any material reference.

Comment: I am not typing out all three. Do you have some particular issue with `ldr`? It's the same story until the instruction decoder, then it's just an additional memory read cycle using the address in `lr` via the purple arrow from the register file to the address generator.

Comment: ok then thanks anyway. I would still like a reference material if you know any.